# Exportar Chart a Excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

estoy finalizando un proyecto en c#.

Genero un reporte mediante una Grafica (chart). que se llena al presionar un botón. con otro botón que se muestra al generar la grafica quiero que pueda Exportarse a Excel o a pdf según y como puedan ayudarme por favor.
La Imagen que muestro es un ejemplo de la grafica que se genera al presionar el boton graficar y el botón que es para exportar a excel

[image: Aquí se aprecia la grafica ya hecha que quiero exportar a Excel o a pdf… como puedan ayudarme por favor]

No tengo código hecho ya que lo que he visto que exportan a excel hacen la grafica mediante código desde la series los nombres y todo lo demás y yo la haría con consulta pero primero quiero que se muestre ene sistema y después darle a el usuario la opción de exportarla tanto como a excel o a pdf.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, no esta claro lo que estas preguntando, se interpreta lo que quieres hacer, pero no el punto en el que necesitas ayuda.. Imagino que no estas buscando que alguien haga todo el trabajo por vos..

Comment: Creo que si esta claro lo que quiero hacer. Por otra parte, no busco que alguien me haga el trabajo, hay veces que veo que ponen algún link donde se muestra como hacerlo o donde haya ejemplos. He buscado por mi cuenta antes de publicar pero no he encontrado resultados.